# How to control the JSON_ARRAYAGG elements order in the resulting JSON string

Tags: mysql, arrays, json

I am testing MySQL `JSON_ARRAY` and `JSON_ARRAYAGG` functions in order to move some application expensive processes to SQL stored functions.

In the following e-commerce application example, I am trying to retrieve a user's cart, not as a resultset of rows from the cart_items table, but as a JSON string containing all the needed information for a Javascript call back function to render the cart.

I have a `cart` table holding the general cart information

```
create table user_cart (
  cart_id  integer unsigned primary key,
  user_id  integer unsigned not null
);
```

and a `cart_item` detail table,

```
create table cart_item (
  cart_item_id  integer unsigned primary key auto_increment,
  cart_id       integer unsigned not null,
  product_id    integer unsigned not null,

  qty           integer unsigned not null,
  ref           varchar(15) not null,

  -- total
  base          double default 0.0,
  tax           double default 0.0,
  tax_pct       double default 0.0,
  total         double default 0.0,

  foreign key (cart_id) references user_cart(cart_id)
);
```

Inserted the following data into the tables

```
insert into user_cart(user_id, cart_id) values
(9001, 30201),
(9001, 30202),
(9001, 30203),
(9001, 30245),
(9001, 30300),
(9001, 30344);

insert into cart_item(cart_id, qty, product_id, ref, base, tax, tax_pct, total) values
(30201, 10, 10551, 'ROB-10551', 12, 2.52, 0.21, 14.52),
(30201, 20, 14313, 'PRT-14313', 11.78, 2.4738, 0.21, 14.2538),
(30201, 10, 12211, 'ROB-12211', 78.05, 16.3905, 0.21, 94.4405),
(30201, 1,  12821, 'COM-12821', 28.02, 5.8842, 0.21, 33.9042),
(30201, 5,  13975, 'DEV-13975', 0.68, 0.1428, 0.21, 0.8228),
(30201, 10, 12662, 'COM-12662', 99.95, 20.9895, 0.21, 120.9395),
(30201, 1,  11590, 'DEV-11590', 100.25, 21.0525, 0.21, 121.3025),
(30201, 1,  13844, 'KIT-13844', 1.12, 0.2352, 0.21, 1.3552),
(30201, 1,  14063, 'DEV-14063', 1.9, 0.399, 0.21, 2.299),
(30201, 3,  14280, 'WRL-14280', 1.67, 0.3507, 0.21, 2.0207),
(30201, 1,  10391, 'ROB-10391', 3.45, 0.7245, 0.21, 4.1745),
(30201, 1,  11021, 'DEV-11021', 4, 0.84, 0.21, 4.84),
(30201, 2,  11884, 'ROB-11884', 18.2, 3.822, 0.21, 22.022);
```

Then, I tried to retrieve the cart items of user `30201` I wrote the following select sentence

```
select json_arrayagg(jobj) from (
  select json_array(product_id, qty, ref, base, tax, tax_pct, total) as jobj
  from cart_item where cart_id = 30201
) as jarray\G
```

that returns

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
json_arrayagg(jobj): [[10551, 10, "ROB-10551", 12.0, 2.52, 0.21, 14.52], [14313, 20, "PRT-14313", 11.78, 2.4738, 0.21, 14.2538], [12211, 10, "ROB-12211", 78.05, 16.3905, 0.21, 94.4405], [12821, 1, "COM-12821", 28.02, 5.8842, 0.21, 33.9042], [13975, 5, "DEV-13975", 0.68, 0.1428, 0.21, 0.8228], [12662, 10, "COM-12662", 99.95, 20.9895, 0.21, 120.9395], [11590, 1, "DEV-11590", 100.25, 21.0525, 0.21, 121.3025], [13844, 1, "KIT-13844", 1.12, 0.2352, 0.21, 1.3552], [14063, 1, "DEV-14063", 1.9, 0.399, 0.21, 2.299], [14280, 3, "WRL-14280", 1.67, 0.3507, 0.21, 2.0207], [10391, 1, "ROB-10391", 3.45, 0.7245, 0.21, 4.1745], [11021, 1, "DEV-11021", 4.0, 0.84, 0.21, 4.84], [11884, 2, "ROB-11884", 18.2, 3.822, 0.21, 22.022]]
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

Scanning the result it can be easily seen that product_ids appear in the following order: 10551, 14313, 12211, 12821, 13975, 12662,..., that is the real order followed to insert the items in the database.

But, when I try to retrieve the items in a different order, let's say ordered by `product_id`, I get the same result as before as if the `order by` clause were ignored.

```
select json_arrayagg(jobj) from (   
  select json_array(product_id, qty, ref, base, tax, tax_pct, total) as jobj   
  from cart_item where cart_id = 30201 order by product_id 
) as jarray\G
```

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
json_arrayagg(jobj): [[10551, 10, "ROB-10551", 12.0, 2.52, 0.21, 14.52], [14313, 20, "PRT-14313", 11.78, 2.4738, 0.21, 14.2538], [12211, 10, "ROB-12211", 78.05, 16.3905, 0.21, 94.4405], [12821, 1, "COM-12821", 28.02, 5.8842, 0.21, 33.9042], [13975, 5, "DEV-13975", 0.68, 0.1428, 0.21, 0.8228], [12662, 10, "COM-12662", 99.95, 20.9895, 0.21, 120.9395], [11590, 1, "DEV-11590", 100.25, 21.0525, 0.21, 121.3025], [13844, 1, "KIT-13844", 1.12, 0.2352, 0.21, 1.3552], [14063, 1, "DEV-14063", 1.9, 0.399, 0.21, 2.299], [14280, 3, "WRL-14280", 1.67, 0.3507, 0.21, 2.0207], [10391, 1, "ROB-10391", 3.45, 0.7245, 0.21, 4.1745], [11021, 1, "DEV-11021", 4.0, 0.84, 0.21, 4.84], [11884, 2, "ROB-11884", 18.2, 3.822, 0.21, 22.022]]
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

Where is it expected to put the `order by` clause to take effect?
Is there any modifier to `JSON_ARRAYAGG` as it appears to be in Oracle DB?

Comment: [The order of `json_arrayagg` is undefined](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg).

Comment: Yes, it is true for a plain json_arrayagg() function. I was wondering if there is any hidden behavior that mimics other implementations as Oracle's or IBM's. In fact, I have been trying to add some `order by` here and there but only syntax errors were achieved

Comment: Adding an `order by` to the nested `select` and exchanging `json_arrayagg()` by `group_concat()` I managed to get an ordered result. The problem with `group_count` is there is a limitation in size that implies changing a system parameter

Answer (score 1):

Use [cursors](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html) like so:

```sql
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS FOO;
CREATE FUNCTION FOO() RETURNS JSON
BEGIN
    DECLARE acc JSON;
    DECLARE a JSON;
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE cursor_ CURSOR FOR
        SELECT 1; # your query here
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    SET acc = JSON_ARRAY();

    OPEN cursor_;
    loop_:
    LOOP
        FETCH cursor_ INTO a;
        IF done THEN LEAVE loop_; END IF;
        SET acc = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(acc, '$', a);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cursor_;

    RETURN acc;
END;
```